# Attempting to Create a Function that calculates the number of weekdays (Monday through Friday)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to create a function that calculates the number of weekdays (Monday through Friday) between two dates inclusively.

I want to name the function "weekdays". If someone could just point me in the right direction (even just how to count the number of weekdays) that would be great thanks!

```
create or replace function weekdays ()
    returns integer as $total$
    declare 
      total integer; 
    begin 
    select count (*) into total from weekdays;
    return total; 
    end; 
    $total$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

I will write pseudo code here.

Dt1 and dt2 are 2 dates
Weekday is a function that returns say 1 for Monday and 7 for Sunday.  All databases have such functions.

```
Cnt=0
For dd in dt1 .. dt2 
    If weekday(dd) is 1 .. 5
        Cnt++
    End if
Next
Return cnt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `generate_series()` to generate all days between the two dates, and count those that are weekdays.

```
create function weekdays(p_start_date date, p_end_date date)
  returns integer
as
$$ 
  select count(*)::int
  from generate_series(p_start_date, p_end_date, interval '1' day) as t(dt)
  where extract(isodow from t.dt) between 1 and 5
$$
language sql;
```

`isodow` returns a number for the day of the week following the ISO 8601 standard where monday is 1 and sunday is 7

The above function can be used like this:

```
select weekdays(date '2019-03-02', date '2019-03-20');
```